# Image wont show up in background

Tags: html, css

I am following a tutorial and trying to get a fixed image as the background to my webpage. In the tutorial the code the person entered works perfectly.  However when I enter the exact same code the image does not appear.  Any reason why?

HTML:

```
<div class="landing">
  <div class="home-wrapper">
    <div class="home-inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home-inner {
  background-image: url("test.jpg");
}
```

Comment: The div has no height so there's nothing to be a background of. Alternatively, could be a path issue.

Comment: You were right, the div needed height. Although the tutorial never included that so idk how they got theres to work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest double checking to make sure path is correct. Also double check that your css file is properly tagged and double check that the file name is correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify height and width every time when you implement an image to your code. So, if you're image has resolution 200px x 200px, you want to implement it in this way:

```
CSS
.home-inner {
  background-image: url("test.jpg");
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```